# jQuery Mobile and Nested ListViews within a Popup

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following popup.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup-settings" data-transition="slideup" data-theme="c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" style="width: 500px; border: 1px solid #A5A5A5;">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-corner-top" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #A5A5A5;">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn-right" style="color: #3498DB;">Done</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="background-color: #f2f2f2; border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li style="background-color: #f2f2f2">
                <img src="icons/settingsMapping.png" /><h2>Mapping</h2><p>Set mapping framework to use.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><h2>Slappy</h2></li>
                    <li><h2>Tappy</h2></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="icons/settingsConnect.png" /><h2>Connection</h2><p>Connect to your Storm V4.0+ Server.</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="icons/settingsPasscode.png" /><h2>Passcode</h2><p>Enter your user name and password.</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="icons/settingsDeveloper.png" /><h2>Developer</h2><p>Developer settings.</p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When it displays, the nested ul is visible all the time.

What I'm looking at doing is when you select a list item from the first list, it's replaced by a second list, all within a popup.

Is this even possible?

Comment: There is a nested lists plugin: https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-nestedlists, but it won't work inside a popup. You could code your own. Another possible solution if you only have 2 levels is to uses a collapsibleset where the top level is a set of collapsibles and each one can expand to show its child list.